# Is it bad to design database that allow user to update PK?

Tags: database

I'm designing database which some tables have modifiable PK, I want to know, is design like this good or bad? Is it make programmer hard to code?

Comment: Maybe more a question for StackOverflow. For example, for tables used for list-of-values, you could use the actual value as PK, instead of introducing a pseudo-ID. With some reference with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, you relatively safe (although updating such a name might trigger a lot of FK updates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad. If the PK is regularly  changed (not as part of some reogrinanization) then it was not a natural PK or the application design is bad.

Comment: What does "part of some reogrinanization" means? Could you give me some example?

Comment: Ekkapop: if you have to change the primary keys when you're completely redesigning your database schema, that's expected.  If you have to update a primary key because somebody got married, that's bad.

Comment: Exactly. Similar would be running out of primary keys and assigning a larger type, for example. Example: Account Numbers - 8 digits, suddenly are 12 digits long. If one uses "real" fields for the PK. This is a reorganinization.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds hard to code for.  You change the primary key for a record, and you have to change all references to that primary key in all tables.  Easy to mess up.  Just use a sequence (or auto_increment or whatever) and make a primary key that isn't data.  Or pick a primary key that's really unlikely to ever need to change.

Comment: Use a [surrogate][1] (or artificial or synthetic) key:
[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of been said, but (my) best practice is to always name a primary key 'id' and make it a serial (autoincrement integer) (identity integer in MSSQL). It's happened to my on many occasions that I had to change the PK when it was some kind of natural key like someone's name.

Comment: If there's an actual PK in the data, there's really no need for a surrogate.